# column "name" of relation "users" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, go

Im trying to insert the user name to a posgres database but i got this error

Im Using heroku  psql.

```
2022/03/01 03:52:54 pq: column "name" of relation "users" does not exist
```

m y code:

```
func createDB(db *sql.DB) {
    // create users table if not exists
    createTableUsers := "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT);"
    statement, err := db.Prepare(createTableUsers)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    statement.Exec()
    log.Println("Created table users")
}

func insertData(db *sql.DB, id string, name string) {
    log.Println("Inserting data")
    insertUser := "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id;"
    err := db.QueryRow(insertUser, name).Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("New record ID is:", id)
}
```

Comment: Do you have a table named `users` aready in the database? Then your createdb function wouldn't do anything and that would explain the problem.